# Tensorflow Dimensions must be equal, but aren't InvalidArgumentError 'loss/dense_loss/sub'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensor

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1619, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 72 and 100 for 'loss/dense_loss/sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [?,72], [?,100].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../src/main/start.py", line 188, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/.../src/main/start.py", line 178, in main
    multi_step_history = multi_step_model.fit(train_data_multi, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=200, validation_data=val_data_multi, validation_steps=50)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
```

The code is here for the most part: https://github.com/githb-throwaway/tensors/blob/master/src/main/start.py

but you can also fully clone and run it locally for debugging purposes, just make sure to run with configuration parameter `--env local` so you don't need to find an API key and stuff.

You will need CUDA 10.1, cudnn-10.1, tensorflow==2.1.0, and a CUDA enabled GPU to run locally.

I'm incredibly new to tensorflow and these dimension errors so I hope that it's something simple I overlooked.

This project was made following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#multi-step_model

Comment: your input dimension is wrong,check the shape of `train_data_multi`

Comment: `<RepeatDataset shapes: ((None, 603, 1), (None, 100)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>` I'm not entirely sure I understand - it doesn't inherently have a shape but it has two TensorSpecs with shapes, are they wrong? @ShubhamShaswat

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions must be equal, but are 72 and 100 for 'loss/dense_loss/sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [?,72], [?,100]
As error is saying you have two tensors of shape [?, 72], [?, 100]. They should have same shape either they are both of [?, 72], [?, 72] or  [?, 100], [?, 100].

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I am just super new to TF so all of this jargon is sorta hullabaloo to me and I really want to understand but for the time being I can't figure out what the solution is, and ofc I can't really ask anyone else to figure it out for me.